# Geometric mean versus arithmetic mean or harmoic mean in multiconductor transmission cable inductance?

Tags: inductor, inductance

In the Electrical Power Transmission And Distribution,if we want to know a inductance of inductor,we will use this formula

[image]
[image]

\$D_{aa'}\$ means the distance between a and a'

In the \$L_P\$.we call the formula, which is in  the numerator, GMD (Geometrical Mean Distance).

In the \$L_P\$.we call the formula, which is in  the denominator, GMR (Geometric Mean Radius).

I am curious about the  \$L_P\$, GMR and GMD,first we can find the inductor (\$L_P\$) = \$2\times10^{-7}ln(\frac{GMD}{GMR})\$

1. Why should (\$L_P\$)= \$2\times10^{-7}ln(\frac{GMD}{GMR})\$, not (\$L_P\$)= \$2\times10^{-7}ln(\frac{GMR}{GMD})\$. Although it seems like a definition, but I believe there must be some reason to explain why should we write \$ln(\frac{GMD}{GMR})\$,not \$ln(\frac{GMR}{GMD})\$.
2. GMD and GMR are both Geometrical Mean, as I know, there are three kind of mean, that is, Arithmetic mean, Geometric Mean, and harmonic mean. Why should we use the geometric mean when we want to find the inductance if inductor, but not using Arithmetic mean or harmoic mean?

Arithmetic mean \$=\frac{a+b}{2}\$

Geometric Mean \$=\sqrt{a \times b}\$

harmonic  mean \$=\frac{2ab}{a+b}\$

Comment: I tidied up your question. I didn't fix "harmoic". Should that be "harmonic"?

Comment: @Transistor yes! sorry for the mistake

Comment: What are a, b, c and x representing in the picture for conductor P?